# What does `{\} {}` mean in `find` command?

Tags: command-line, find, split

Please explain this command in detail.

I am using this command to find large files above 6 MB and split them into 5 MB chunks in the same folder. Then it removes the original files (larger than 6MB) in the same directory.

```
find . -size +6M -exec split -d -b 5M {\} {}-part \; | find . -size +6M -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I have no idea about the purpose of the following portion of the command:

```
{\} {}
```

My aim is to develop a script for backing up Virtualmin domains to Amazon S3 buckets monthly.

Due to a 5 GB PUT limit on Amazon S3, I have to split the domain backups (`tar.gz`) in sizes less than 5 GB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manpage of find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

> The string `{}' is replaced by the current file name being  processed
>   everywhere  it  occurs  in  the  arguments to the command...

So, the first part of the `find` command searches for files greater than 6 MB and executes (`-exec`) `split` on every found file.

For Example, if the found file is `./path/to/file`, the command executed would be:

```
split -d -b 5M ./path/to/file ./path/to/file-part
```

`{}` is the placeholder replaced with the filepath. The `{\}` is unnecessary it could also be `{}`.

In the second find command - the one after the pipe (`|`) - the `find` command calls `rm -rf` for every file.

Comment: It's also wrong to use the pipe `|` to separate the commands; I'd recommend using the logical and `&&` separator so that the second command only runs if the first was successful. Now the second find could be deleting files that haven't yet been split.

Comment: As adviced by @wurtel the script can be `find . -size +6M -exec sh -c 'split -d -b 5M {} {}-part && rm {}' \;`